# Why the example of Token Contract contains mintToken function?

Tags: tokens

I'm examining the token example given on this page https://www.ethereum.org/token

For what cases mintToken function can be included in a token contract? Can someone trust a token that can uncontrollable increase balance of any account?

Can I just delete this function from my contract without having problems with my token in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I just delete this function from my contract without having
>   problems with my token in future?

Yes you can, it is optional (in your example).

> For what cases mintToken function can be included in a token contract?

If your initial assigned supply was too small or without initial supply you have minted very small amount of tokens during ICO. Knowing that the contract is immutable it can be very useful to have this function.

> Can someone trust a token that can uncontrollable increase balance of any account?

It depends on whether you trust person (company) who controls the owners account or not. I would say if there are no hardcoded limitations on amount of mintable tokens in smart contract, you cannot fully trust it.

Answer (score 0):

A method to mint tokens can be somewhat helpful depending on how you want to manage the supply of your token.

In most cases a mint function will be helpful if you want to sell tokens during an ICO at a fixed price.

For example, i decide to create an ICO and sell my tokens to a fixed price of 1ETH/token. This way, i can emit a number of tokens equals to the number of ETHs i received.

In this example i can decide to create a cap afterwhich no token will be emitted anymore, but if i don't reach the cap, the supply of tokens will still be the number of ETHs i received.